# Update two data values using a Select input and v-model

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a simple Select input, binded to a data property (`device_id`) using v-model:

```
<select v-model="device_id">
  <option disabled value="">Choose a device</option>
  <option v-for="device in devices" v-bind:value="device.id">
    {{ device.name }}
  </option>
</select>
```

When the user picks a device, `this.device_id` is updated automatically, which is great! I can then save that to my database.

However... I also want to save `this.device_name` and for the life of me, I can't figure out how to "bind" or update both `this.device_id` AND `this.device_name` when the user clicks on an option.

I tried adding `@click="updateName(device.name)"` to my `<option>` tag, and then that method would update the second data property.

However this only works on Firefox, since other browsers don't trigger a click event on `<option>`. Besides it feels like kind of a weird/hacky way to do this.

Just to be clear, my question is: **How can I update two data properties when the user clicks on an option?**

I am sure there is a "correct" way and I would love to hear your ideas! This feels like a very straightforward problem and yet I can't seem to figure it out -_-

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to bind the option value to the whole object and then work with properties of your selected one like :

```
<select v-model="selected_device">
  <option disabled value="">Choose a device</option>
  <option v-for="device in devices" v-bind:value="device">
    {{ device.name }}
  </option>
</select>
```

to send the id to your database just use `this.selected_device.id` and you could also use `selected_device.name`

Comment: Thank you! That worked great and was the obvious solution that I completely missed, haha